# Are Americans popular in the Philippines?

Tags: us-citizens, philippines, cultural-awareness

I know that the U.S. and Philippines have a long history together.  We were allies in WW2.  But these days, what is the average Filipino perception and disposition towards U.S. civilians?

Also, what are some honest ways to be culturally sensitive?

Comment: I'd remove the second part as it's really a different question.  Also it might help to explain what you'd accept as an answer - evidence of animosity, or a survey, or what? Currently it's not totally clear (to me anyway) how one might go about answering this, aside from anecdotes?

Comment: This question is not about travel/

Comment: I disagree completely @SantaC..  To me one of the main points, or at least benefits, of traveling is meeting people with a different background and experience than my own.  Trying to get started on a positive foot is, I believe, very beneficial to the traveling experience.  If I accidentally end up offending a lot of natives, that will ruin my trip.

Comment: If a question on whether it's safe to be an Israeli tourist in various muslim countries is OK and whether it's safe to be an Armenian tourist in Turkey is OK then this has to be OK too.

Comment: @hippietrail I understand that it is opinion based.  I don't agree that it's not related to travel.

Comment: @Gn13l: If I parse your multiple negatives then we do agree, though I guess we both disagree with some other parties here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general Filipinos are almost universally nice to everyone, there are some exceptions with older people and certain countries (Japan, basically). Many people from the US retired or work here and Filipinos will generally show deference to any westerner and treat them politely. Most Filipinos I know are aware of the history but it doesn't really colour their current thinking, they just default to treating people politely.

Be aware that Western = Rich in many peoples minds and that will make you a target for scams and things, but that's not specifically a US thing.

I don't think I can answer your second question expect by saying just be polite, don't take advantage of peoples kindness, treat people with respect, try and get to know people and their life. Be aware that many people may not want to talk about politics or the history of the country, partly because it doesn't affect many peoples day-to-day lives as they see it and partly as they would want to avoid arguments if your views differed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I find it very helpful.  It sounds like most Filipinos that I'll encounter will likely have experience with people from many nations.  I really had no idea whether or not the Philippines was more international or isolated.  It sounds very international.

Comment: In the cities and tourist areas it's pretty international. Out in the provinces a foreigner will be a bit more of a rarity but people will still be generally friendly. In general, due to the American presence here after the war the place is a lot more westernized compared to other cities in SE Asia.

Comment: I wasn't even sure that there had been a persistent American presence after WW2.  I'll not be traveling outside the touristy areas.

Comment: @Gn13l The Philippines were colony of the United States from 1898 until after WWII, so Americans have been fairly common in the cities there pretty much continuously for over 100 years. Incidentally, the first scheduled trans-Pac passenger flight was San Francisco to Manila. The Philippines wasn't just an ally of the U.S. during WWII, it was still technically _part of the U.S._ at that time. At any rate, SpaceDog's answer seems to be very accurate from my experience (both regarding cities and the provinces.) People are very friendly in both, but will be curious and/or shy in the provinces.